# Using Python to run executable and fill in user input

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm trying to use Python to automate a process that involves calling a Fortran executable and submitting some user inputs.  I've spent a few hours reading through similar questions and trying different things, but haven't had any luck.  Here is a minimal example to show what I tried last

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

# Calling executable 
ps = subprocess.Popen('fortranExecutable',shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
ps.communicate('argument 1')
ps.communicate('argument 2')
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
  File "gridGen.py", line 216, in <module>
    ps.communicate(outputName)
  File "/opt/apps/python/epd/7.2.2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 737, in communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Any suggestions or pointers are greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

When I call the Fortran executable, it asks for user input as follows:

```
fortranExecutable
Enter name of input file: 'this is where I want to put argument 1'
Enter name of output file: 'this is where I want to put argument 2'
```

Somehow, I need to run the executable, wait until it asks for user input and then supply that input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the input doesn't depend on the previous answers then you could pass them all at once using `.communicate()`:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('fortranExecutable', stdin=PIPE) #NOTE: no shell=True here
p.communicate(os.linesep.join(["input 1", "input 2"]))
```

`.communicate()` waits for process to terminate therefore you may call it at most once.

Comment: it says like this for me  `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @KuneMohith the code is for Python 2 (where `str` is `bytes` type). Pass `text=True` or `encoding` parameter to Popen() on the current Python version.

Comment: @KuneMohith: e.g., `subprocess.run('fortranExecutable', input="\n".join(["input 1", "input 2"]), text=True)` (tested on Python 3.7)

Answer (score 1):

As the [spec says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) `communicate()` awaits for the subprocess to terminate, so the second call will be addressed to the finished process.

If you want to interact with the process, use [`p.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin)&Co instead (mind the deadlock warning).

Answer (score 0):

By the time, you reach ps.communicate('argument 2'), ps process is already closed as ps.communicate('argument 1') waits until EOF.
I think, if you want to write multiple times at stdin, you might have to use:

```
ps.stdin.write('argument 1')
ps.stdin.write('argument 2')
```

Comment: I tried this, but still got an error.  See above edit for clarification of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

your arguments should not be passed to communicate. they should be given in the call to Popen, like:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Comment: The problem is that the executable runs and then asks for user input.  I need to wait until the user input is requested and then fill in that input.  There are three inputs total.