# How to run executable with input file using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, cmd

I am running an executable from cmd:

```
*.exe input.inp
```

I want to run it using python and tried following:

```
os.system('"*.exe"')
```

But don't know how to specify input file as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to execute a python script file with an argument from inside another python script file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230725/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-from-inside-another-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python to run executable and fill in user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522267/using-python-to-run-executable-and-fill-in-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('fortranExecutable', stdin=PIPE) #NOTE: no shell=True here
p.communicate(os.linesep.join(["input 1", "input 2"]))
```

For more please refer to:

[Using Python to run executable and fill in user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522267/using-python-to-run-executable-and-fill-in-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

I had to launch cmd window and specify input file location from within Python script. [This page](http://sharats.me/the-ever-useful-and-neat-subprocess-module.html) was really helpful in getting it done.

I used `Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'command'])` from above page and replaced `'/K'` with `'/C'` in it to run and close the cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system(r'pathToExe.exe inputFileOrWhateverOtherCommand')
```